# Issues with offset aware and offset naive times

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone

I am using the following code snippet to detect if a particular time falls within 2 times(All set for the UTC timezone). This code however throws an exception complaining that i am comparing a offset aware time with a offset naive time. I was hoping to get some insight on this.

```
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc).time()
t1 = datetime.time(9, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
t2 = datetime.time(11, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
if t1 < currentTime and t2 > currentTime:
    return True
return False
```

Comment: Since the offset from UTC depends on the time zone and these change over the years, it doesn't make much sense to have time without a date having a UTC offset. Here, you could for example compare time and UTC offset separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What appears to have been happening here is I was losing the timezone in converting to time.

To rectify this. I had to do the following.

```
currentTime =  currentTime.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
```